# Protected constructor accessible in sibling-class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, access-modifiers

I have 1 abstract class: `Model<E>` with 2 implementations: `ItemModel` and `ItemLogModel`. The constructor of `ItemLogModel` is protected, but it is still accessible from `ItemModel`. I expect the protected constructor to only be accessible by subclasses of `ItemLogModel`. Can someone explain to me why this is possible?

Code:

```
public abstract class Model<E> implements IModel {
    private final Repository<? extends IModel, E> _repository;
    protected E _entity;

    protected Model(Repository<? extends IModel, E> repository, E entity) 
        this._repository = repository;
        this._entity = entity;
    }        
    ...
}

public class ItemModel extends Model<Item> implements IItem {
    ...

    @Override
    public void setStatus(Status status, String logMessage) throws Exception {
        super._entity.setStatus(status.toString());
        super.update();

        // CALLING protected constructor here!
        new ItemLogModel(this, logMessage);
    }
}

public class ItemLogModel extends Model<ItemLog> implements IItemLog {

    protected ItemLogModel(ItemModel itemModel, String message) throws Exception {
        super(REPOSITORY, new ItemLog());
        super._entity.setAccessPointBean(itemModel.getEntity());
        super._entity.setStatus(itemModel.getStatus().toString());
        super._entity.setMessage(message);
        super.save();
    }

}
```

Comment: `protected` members are visible to the same package as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey okay, thanks! I did not realize that

Comment: Just to add reference to @PeterLawrey comment : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1 : `if the member or constructor is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:

    Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is declared.

    Access is correct as described in §6.6.2.`

Comment: Here's a [good table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) illustrating the scope of protected.